# Controlling scroll position for Facebook iFrame application's parent frame

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've got a Facebook iFrame application happily up and running, but I'm realizing that I don't have a way to handle the scroll position of the parent frame because of cross-domain issues.  If a user clicks too far down on the page, I can't pop them back up to the top.

Has anyone had an luck with either any of the Facebook JS libraries or other JavaScript trickery to pull this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Facebook added the FB.Canvas.scrollTo method to the new JavaScript SDK on April 2011:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Comment: It's true, there's finally a way to do this!  Thanks much for sharing — hopefully this will help out whoever else has been attempting to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

This works better for me (assumes use of Jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        scrollTo(0,0);
    });

    function scrollTo(x,y){
        $("body").append('<iframe id="scrollTop" style="border:none;width:1px;height:1px;position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-100px;" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/xd_receiver_v0.4.php?r=1#%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22sc%22%3Anull%2C%22sf%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sr%22%3A2%2C%22h%22%3A%22iframeOuterServer%22%2C%22sid%22%3A%220.957%22%2C%22t%22%3A0%7D%5B0%2C%22iframeInnerClient%22%2C%22scrollTo%22%2C%7B%22x%22%3A'+x+'%2C%22y%22%3A'+y+'%7D%2Cfalse%5D" onload="$(\'#scrollTop\').remove();"></iframe>');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  It works well in the Canvas App iframe, but it doesn't work in Facebook's new iframe in Page tab.  Is there a comparable solution that works in iframe in Page tab?

Answer (score 1):

The old library had some functions that worked, but they haven't been ported over to the new Javascript SDK library yet as of mid-June.

Added 10/12: Try using location.href("#top") to position the page as necessary.  A little clunky, but better than nothing.  You can position it anywhere you can put an ID or  reference.

Comment: It's true, the old library had some functions for doing some of this (though not for what I'd mentioned here, unfortunately), but it seems like they're not quite functional in the new library yet -- caused some very strange issues when last I tried.  

Thanks much just the same!